# How to randomize Multiple Question Choice with Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms, google-form-quiz

I am making a Google Form with Apps Script. The Google Form contains multiple choice questions.

As I want to make the Google Form a quiz, I want to randomize the choice order of the MC questions.

How can I randomize the choices/answers with Apps Script?

Here is my code:

```
item=form.addMultipleChoiceItem();
    item.setTitle(Question);
    if (Ans == "A"){
    item.setChoices([item.createChoice(ChoiceA, true),item.createChoice(ChoiceB,false),item.createChoice(ChoiceC,false),item.createChoice(ChoiceD,false)]);};
        if (Ans == "B"){
    item.setChoices([item.createChoice(ChoiceA, false),item.createChoice(ChoiceB,true),item.createChoice(ChoiceC,false),item.createChoice(ChoiceD,false)]);};
        if (Ans == "C"){
    item.setChoices([item.createChoice(ChoiceA, false),item.createChoice(ChoiceB,false),item.createChoice(ChoiceC,true),item.createChoice(ChoiceD,false)]);};
        if (Ans == "D"){
    item.setChoices([item.createChoice(ChoiceA, false),item.createChoice(ChoiceB,false),item.createChoice(ChoiceC,false),item.createChoice(ChoiceD,true)]);};
    item.setPoints(1);
    item.setRequired(true);
```

Comment: When you're asking string Javascript Questions you would be wise to add Javascript tag.

Answer (score 0):

```
function pickRandomQuestion(numberOfQuestions) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random()*(numberOfQuestions))+1;
}
```

returns 1 to number of questions